# Hitting User Quota Limits

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I'm currently using this Script to grab all my contacts into a Google Sheet. Ideally I'd like to have it run as often as possible. With a trigger set to every 1hr, I receive the following quota limit.

> Temporary problem - please try again later and consider using batch operations. The user is over quota.

Is there a more efficient way to batch the following script so that it can run more often? Or maybe only when a contact has been updated/created?

```
function onOpen()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push( {name: "Read Contacts", functionName: "readContacts"} );
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Contacts", menuEntries);
};


function readContacts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");

  sheet.clear();
  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Apptivo Contacts');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
//var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var ContactArray  = new Array();
  var ContactArrays = [];

  ContactArray = [];
  ContactArray.push("");
  ContactArray.push("FullName");
  ContactArray.push("Emails");
  ContactArray.push("PhoneNumbers");
//ContactArray.push("HomePhone");
//ContactArray.push("WorkPhone");
  ContactArray.push("Company");
  ContactArray.push("Job Title");
  ContactArray.push("Notes");  
  ContactArray.push("HomeAddress");
  ContactArray.push("WorkAddress");
  ContactArray.push("URL");
  ContactArray.push("Groups");
//ContactArray.push("Group1");
//ContactArray.push("Group2");

  ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);

  for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
  { 
    ContactArray = [];
    ContactArray.push("");
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getFullName());

  //Emails
    var Emails = "";
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getEmails().length;g++)
    {
      Emails += contacts[i].getEmails()[g].getAddress();
      if (g + 1 == contacts[i].getEmails().length) break
      Emails += "\n";
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(Emails);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}


  //Phone Numbers
    var Phones = "";    
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getPhones().length;g++)
    {
      if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "MOBILE_PHONE") {
        Phones += "C: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_PHONE") {
        Phones += "W: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_PHONE") {
        Phones += "H: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else {
        Phones += "O: "
      }
      Phones += contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getPhoneNumber();
      if (g + 1 == contacts[i].getPhones().length) break
      Phones += "\n" ;
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(Phones);}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getCompanyName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getCompanies()[0].getJobTitle());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getNotes());

  //Addresses
    var homeAddress = "" , workAddress = "";     
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getAddresses().length;g++)
    {
      if (contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getLabel() == "HOME_ADDRESS") {
        homeAddress += contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getAddress();
      } else if (contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getLabel() == "WORK_ADDRESS") {
        workAddress += contacts[i].getAddresses()[g].getAddress();
      }
    }

    try{ContactArray.push(homeAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    try{ContactArray.push(workAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}  

    //ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getAddresses().getAddress()); 

    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getUrls()[0].getAddress());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

    var ListofGroups = "";    
    for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getContactGroups().length;g++)
    {
      ListofGroups += contacts[i].getContactGroups()[g].getName();
      ListofGroups += " | ";
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(ListofGroups);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getContactGroups()[1].getName());}
  //catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getContactGroups()[2].getName());}
  //catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}


    ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,ContactArrays.length,ContactArrays[0].length).setValues(ContactArrays);
};
```

Comment: How long does your script take to execute and is this a G Suite or consumer account (consumer accounts are those that end with @gmail.com). Consumer accounts have a total trigger execution time of 1 hour per day, which means that the script cannot take longer than 75 seconds on average if you want it to fire every 30 minutes. You have batched everything properly as you only have 1 read from Google Contacts and 1 write to a spreadsheet.

Comment: this is a G Suite account. it takes about 2min to run the script.. but I don't remember it taking that long before. Maybe because i have more contacts now...

Comment: either way I should have 6 hrs of execution time which should be more than enough. Am I hitting a different quota with fetching contact information?

Comment: All quotas are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) or in the [script dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard). So assuming the script doesn't do anything else at all you shouldn't be hitting any other listed quotas. Unless this is your first billing cycle and you have more than 6 users in the domain, in which case you are still subject to consumer level quotas.

Comment: its not our first billing cycle. We've been using G Suite for a few years now. This is really odd... There is no other part to the script. what you see there is everything. There has to be something wrong that is causing this.. I'll try and get a second set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Zaq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/135384/zaq), I reduced the number of `get*` calls in my script -- these calls are what drained the Google Services quota.

The script now takes a fraction of the time to run. (from 2mins to under 20sec)

Although they don't affect the quotas, I used `map` and `join` methods of JavaScript arrays to shorten some code.

My end result...

```
function readContacts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contacts");

  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('Apptivo Contacts');
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);
  var ContactArray  = new Array();
  var ContactArrays = [];

  ContactArray = [];
  ContactArray.push("");
  ContactArray.push("FullName");
  ContactArray.push("Emails");
  ContactArray.push("PhoneNumbers");
  ContactArray.push("Company");
  ContactArray.push("Job Title");
  ContactArray.push("Notes");  
  ContactArray.push("HomeAddress");
  ContactArray.push("WorkAddress");
  ContactArray.push("URL");
  ContactArray.push("Groups");

  ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);

  for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++)
  { 
    ContactArray = [];
    ContactArray.push("");

  //FullName
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getFullName());

  //Emails
    var Emails = contacts[i].getEmails().map(function(email) {
      return email.getAddress();
      }).join("\n");

    try{ContactArray.push(Emails);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Phone Numbers
    var Phones = "";
    var contactPhones = contacts[i].getPhones();    
    for ( var g=0;g<contactPhones.length;g++)
    {
      if (contactPhones[g].getLabel() == "MOBILE_PHONE") {
        Phones += "C: "
      } else if (contactPhones[g].getLabel() == "WORK_PHONE") {
        Phones += "W: "
      } else if (contactPhones[g].getLabel() == "HOME_PHONE") {
        Phones += "H: "
      } else if (contactPhones[g].getLabel() == "HOME_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else if (contactPhones[g].getLabel() == "WORK_FAX") {
        Phones += "F: "
      } else {
        Phones += "O: "
      }
      Phones += contactPhones[g].getPhoneNumber();
      if (g + 1 == contactPhones.length) break
      Phones += "\n" ;
    }
    try{ContactArray.push(Phones);}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Company
    var contactCompany = contacts[i].getCompanies();
    try{ContactArray.push(contactCompany[0].getCompanyName());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //JobTitle
    try{ContactArray.push(contactCompany[0].getJobTitle());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Notes  
    ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getNotes());

  //Addresses
    var homeAddress = "" , workAddress = "";
    var contactAddresses = contacts[i].getAddresses();
    for ( var g=0;g<contactAddresses.length;g++)
    {
      if (contactAddresses[g].getLabel() == "HOME_ADDRESS") {
        homeAddress += contactAddresses[g].getAddress();
      } else if (contactAddresses[g].getLabel() == "WORK_ADDRESS") {
        workAddress += contactAddresses[g].getAddress();
      }
    }
    //Home
    try{ContactArray.push(homeAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
    //Work
    try{ContactArray.push(workAddress);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}  

  //URLs  
    try{ContactArray.push(contacts[i].getUrls()[0].getAddress());}
    catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}

  //Groups
    var Groups = contacts[i].getContactGroups().map(function(group) {
      return group.getName();
      }).join(" | ");
    try{ContactArray.push(Groups);}
      catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}


    ContactArrays.push(ContactArray);
  }

  //If Array is not blank(to avoid quota issues)
 if (12 < ContactArrays.length) {
  // Re-populate sheet
   sheet.clear();
   sheet.getRange(1,1,ContactArrays.length,ContactArrays[0].length).setValues(ContactArrays);
   }

};
```